# Why does React re-render differently whether the state is an object vs a string?

Tags: reactjs

The below React example, `userProfile` state is an **object**: 
1st render: state is `{}` 
2nd render: state is `res.data` 
-> infinite re-rendering

If `userProfile` is changed to a **string** e.g. `useState('')` with `setUserProfile(res.data.bio)` 
1st render: state is `''` 
2nd render: state is `res.data.bio` 
3rd render: state is `res.data.bio` 
-> stops re-rendering after the 3rd

**Two questions:**

- Why does React re-render differently depending on whether `userProfile` state is an object vs a string?
- When `userProfile` is a string, why does React stop re-rendering after the 3rd render instead of after the 2nd one?

---

App.js

```
import UserProfile from './UserProfile';

const App = () => {
    const login = 'facebook';
    
    return (
        <Router>
            <Link to={`/user/${login}`}>Fetch Facebook bio from GitHub</Link>
            <Route path='/user/:login' component={UserProfile} />
        </Router>
    );
};
```

UserProfile.js

```
const UserProfile = ({ match }) => {
    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState({});

    const getUser = async username => {
        const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        setUserProfile(res.data);
    };

    getUser(match.params.login);
// intentionally not using useEffect(() => { getUser(match.params.login); }, []);

    return (<p>{userProfile.bio}</p>);
};
```

Comment: re: second question. for those interested into why React re-runs the same function again before bailing out. Dan Abramov explains the reason here on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14994#issuecomment-468779750)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React checks if a state variable has changed, and if so, it rerenders. Since no matter how many times you compare two objects (even if they look identical), they will always be different, React will keep rerendering.

A string, on the other hand, is a primitive type and thus compares differently. Try this:

```
console.log({d: 3} === {d: 3})
console.log("sss" === "sss")
```

And it will give you an idea as to why this happens.

So even though you keep setting the state var to the same object, it's not really the same. But a string IS the same so it stops rerendering.

Check out this article on Object equality in JS: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Now let me address your second question:

> When userProfile is a string, why does React stop re-rendering after the 3rd render instead of after the 2nd one?

If you look at the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update), you will run into these 2 paragraphs, which, I believe answer your question:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React
> won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing
> expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with
> useMemo

Note the second paragraph.

Comment: +1 ahh I see, that's great to know, In the 2nd render, state is 'bio' string and setState sets state to the same 'bio' value, so how come React doesn't stop here, but instead does a 3rd render?

Comment: @d.c good question. Check out the answer in the updated post.

Comment: there it is. was driving me crazy. thanks so much!