# Do updating state of an object inside the useEffect() creates a new object?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, use-state

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function CountSecrets() {
  const [secret, setSecret] = useState({ value: "", countSecrets: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (secret.value === 'secret') {
      setSecret(s => ({...s, countSecrets: s.countSecrets + 1}));    }
  }, [secret]);
  const onChange = ({ target }) => {
    setSecret(s => ({ ...s, value: target.value }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={secret.value} onChange={onChange} />
      <div>Number of secrets: {secret.countSecrets}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when the **secret** is typed the react goes into an infinite loop

I am reading this code through a blog post and its written that the setting the state of an object inside the useEffect **creates a new object** so the dependency inside the **[ ] of useEffect
changes and cause infinite loop**.

Here is my question when we type and onchange  is triggered and is also updating the state, so is updating the state inside the onchange do not creates a new object?And what are the cases of creation of new objects ?

Here is the link of the blog (its the second point) [Link](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-infinite-loop/)

Comment: It does not create a new object. The problem lies with comparing objects in JS; 2 objects are NEVER the same, even if they contain identical key/values. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66058022/1927991

Comment: Updating state does not automatically creates a new object, it is your responsibility to provide a new object to React each time your state is changed, which you do in all the above cases.

Comment: But I am updating the state, so does that creates the new object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thumb rule in React is that state object is immutable, can not change it directly. So whenever you want to update state you always create new objects.

Looking at your code, new objects created in both the cases in `onChange` as well as in `useEffects`. But `useEffects` creates infinite loop as dependency gets changed whereas onChange does not create infinite loop as state update does not `onChange` again

if you want to avoid an infinite loop, I suggest 2 ways.

- Change the dependency array from `[secret] --> [secret.value]`
- Or have these 2 values `value, countSecrets`as 2 different state

In summary, when you have object as state then you should always create new object and set it. Where as for value based state,  react will take care of it.

Comment: By your answer you want to say that when onChange is triggered, it creates new object and then new object does not trigger the onChange again.
While object creation in useEffect triggers the useEffect every time as the dependency is changing with the creating of new object and so on .

Comment: Yes absolutely. OnChange is not triggered again like useEffect does so you wont get infinite loop incase of onChange

Comment: Thanks for making efforts and clearing my doubt :)